# How do I import "sibling" packages?

Tags: go

Assume my project's file structure is this:

```
.
├── main.go
└── ui
    ├── controls
    │   ├── control.go
    │   ├── constants.go
    │   ├── container.go
    │   ├── label.go
    └── views
        └── view.go
```

All files in `ui/controls` are in a package called `controls` and `view.go` is in the `views` package. I want code in the `views` package to be able to reference an interface defined in `control.go`.

I'm using Go 1.14. Is what I want possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. You need to provide a full path on import, as usual.

E.g. if you module is `github.com/peterw/myproject` (*), then to import the `controls` package from a file in the `views` package, you'd do:

```
import "github.com/peterw/myproject/ui/controls"
```

(*) This means that in your `go.mod` file the module is defined with:

```
module github.com/peterw/myproject
```

Comment: Define "full path", please. I need to be able to compile this project on various platforms and I can't assume the project folder will always have the same name or be in the same location in the file system.

Comment: @PeterW.: if you're not familiar with using Go modules, consider reading something like https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/simple-go-project-layout-with-modules/ and then the official docs

Comment: Go depends excessively on source control systems ...

Comment: You literally cannot build your code (let alone run unit tests!) without checking it in and pushing to the repository ... what am I missing ?